# Even if I only create one item of a set, I still get the bonus of multiple traits, no?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Let's say I pick the item set Magnus' Gift, which needs 4 traits for each item.

Let's say I only craft a staff from that set.

I still get the bonus from having 4 traits on a single weapon, even though I haven't crafted any of the other items in the set, right?

If so then this would mean that when it becomes time to craft another item for my character, I would be foolish not to craft it from a set, even if I mismatch everything and don't get any set bonuses?

Note, my character in question is still levelling. I have a VR1 character where I can craft a lot of stuff but I'm playing on my sorcerer which is mid-30s right now so mismatched set items is not a problem.

But the bonus traits would be quite useful.

Can anyone confirm this? I am still not able to craft any from the Magnus' Gift set because I'm currently researching the 3rd trait for the lightning staff, which would be the first item that would be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're understanding this wrong.

When you see this information, e.g. **Magnus' Gift** being associated with **4 traits**, this just refers to the requirement to actually craft a specific item in this set.

So, for example, if you only know one or two different traits for *medium boots*, you won't be able to craft the medium boots of the **Magnus' Gift** set.

If you know 5 different traits for lightning staves, you'll be able to craft a lightning staff of the **Magnus' Gift** set using any of these 5 traits.

The crafted item will still only come with the selected trait (only one per item).

Comment: OK, so it is only a requirement to *know* the requisite number of traits, I still pick just one for the item. Well, that sucks :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen correct. One trait per item, that's fixed